# How to use R ggplot to Plot datatable colume values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I currently have some table like below, and i would like to plot Time(as x-axis), and Ask(as y axis) by using ggplot2(),

```
> data
                      Time     Ask     Bid Ask_Vol Bid_Vol
1  2013.03.01 00:05:01.469 1.30600 1.30608    1.50    2.25
2  2013.03.01 00:05:04.329 1.30600 1.30607    1.50    1.50
3  2013.03.01 00:05:05.499 1.30600 1.30607    1.50    1.50
4  2013.03.01 00:05:07.320 1.30598 1.30607    1.73    6.38
5  2013.03.01 00:05:07.909 1.30598 1.30606    1.73    2.25
6  2013.03.01 00:05:08.820 1.30598 1.30605    1.73    1.50
7  2013.03.01 00:05:09.011 1.30597 1.30602    1.73    1.50
8  2013.03.01 00:05:09.250 1.30594 1.30600    1.50    2.25
9  2013.03.01 00:05:09.310 1.30593 1.30600    1.73    2.25
10 2013.03.01 00:05:09.991 1.30592 1.30599    2.10    1.50
```

I have tried

```
ggplot(data, aes(Time, Ask)) + geom_line())
```

and it gives me an empty chart and a line of message which i have no idea what this is. first time using R, i am a newbie, thanks for help

```
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

Comment: What does `sapply(data, class)` say? Also, please add `dput(data)`.

Comment: i see, thanks for the tips, Time is as "character", rests are set as "numeric", and now the problems would be how to convert the string type to values the represents them on time series chart

Comment: `data$Time <- strptime(data$Time, "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: thanks again khashaa, is there a way to include the milisecond as well? i am looking for the symbol for it, i have tried to use .%OS at the end but it puts all time as <NA>

Comment: Using as.`POSIXct` rather than `strptime` actually works with %OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what type of x-axis labels you want, but this can get you started, hopefully.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Convert time to proper class
data$Time <- as.POSIXct(data$Time, format="%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%OS")

# Plot using the basic qplot function
qplot(Time, Ask, data = data) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Hehe my pleasure, dear